# Parallel execution instead of foreach

Tags: php, multithreading, performance, foreach, php-7

I currently do file upload sequentially with a `foreach` loop.Each upload is processed one after the other.

```
<?php
foreach ($files_array as $file) {
//each image is processed here and upload one after the other
}
?>
```

However processing multiple images instead of one at a time would be more efficient as the user will wait a lot less.How can i process multiple files at once in php instead of doing it sequentially with a foreach

Comment: Upload the files parallel with each their own request.

Comment: File upload from user perspective is already fast.Nginx take care of the upload and then pass to backend(php).I am trying to make backend process faster here

Comment: I think you don't understand the consequence. PHP is single-threaded, if you want to do things parallel, you either install pthreads or the simple solution is to make multiple requests instead, so each image gets processed on their own.

Comment: This would really depend on what processing entails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Option 1 - fork your process:

You need to fork your process, and fulfill this in few threads. Here my example:

```
<?php

declare(ticks = 1);

$filesArray = [
    'file-0',
    'file-1',
    'file-2',
    'file-3',
    'file-4',
    'file-5',
    'file-6',
    'file-7',
    'file-8',
    'file-9',
];

$maxThreads = 3;
$child = 0;

pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, function ($signo) {
    global $child;
    if ($signo === SIGCLD) {
        while (($pid = pcntl_wait($signo, WNOHANG)) > 0) {
            $signal = pcntl_wexitstatus($signo);
            $child--;
        }
    }
});
foreach ($filesArray as $item) {
    while ($child >= $maxThreads) {
        sleep(1);
    }
    $child++;
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if ($pid) {
    } else {
        // Here your stuff.
        sleep(2);
        echo posix_getpid()." - $item \n";
        exit(0);
    }
}
while ($child != 0) {
    sleep(3);
}
```

#### Option 2 - use work queues:

You can also use queue (for example RabbitMQ or something else).

In your script you can put your job into queue and reply to client that job added to queue and will processed soon. [Here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-php.html) you can find detailed example how you can done it with RabbitMQ.

Comment: Thanks for the approach.I also read about job queues...what do you think about it , is it going to be worth it in such a use case

Comment: @user2650277 Yes, using queue nice approach too! But you have to decide what you need: a) quick process all files and reply to client immediately; or b) reply to client that you put job in queue and will proccess it soon. I've also added option 2 to my answer. Hope it will help you.

Comment: I need a) in my case with quick processing being the key here.I also saw beanstalkd --> https://jtreminio.com/2015/12/queues-working-smart-faster-in-parallel/ but i am not really sure it will work with PHP7.I need to figure out how to add  queue support to my class

Answer (score -2):

You want to upload multiple images at a time ?

If yes so use the "explode" method to upload multiple images.